# Send polish characters in ISO-8859-1 environment with a html form

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I have the following problem:

I have a webpage with a ISO-8859-1 charset.

Inside this page i have  a form with the argument

```
accept-charset="UTF-8"
```

The form will be send with the post method

Now i want to submit polish letters mixed with latin letters

> test ł,ą,ę,ś,ć,ż,ź,ó test

And want to display the result with PHP.

I tried several combinations of mb_convert_encoding, utf8_encode / utf8_decode, iconv and everything else. But the display is not right.

I just want to say to the browser: the page charset is iso-8859-1 but this small area is UTF-8

Comment: Why not using UTF8 for the whole page?

Comment: Polish characters are in iso-8859-2

Comment: The problem is: the text displayed on this page comes from several sources and countries (navision database, product-catalogue database, vendor-description texts out of a excel-file and so on) and everything is iso-8859-1 since years. i had to change the encoding of every file generation process or import process. and, to be honest, i don't know where all of them are or come from

Comment: @Orangepill the polish letters are only an example. i don't want to change everything when my boss decides to accept swedish characters too. i guess utf-8 will catch the most (maybe some asians characters will get lost)

Comment: try `<form accept-charset="ISO-8859-1 UTF-8">`

Comment: Utf-8 covers that too. And the first 128 code points on iso-8859-1 and utf-8 are identical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do anything with *character encoding conversion* here. Polish characters simply cannot be encoded in ISO-8859-1, full stop. If you do not want to change the encoding of your website to an encoding which *can* encode Polish and other characters (such as ISO-8859-2, UTF-8 or similar), all you can do is to represent these characters as **HTML entities**:

```
echo htmlentities($utf8Text, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

You cannot make *part* of the page be encoded in a different encoding.

Comment: ok i understand that. let's say i'll get the right encoding and can save it  proper to the database. but how can i refill the form to allow editing with the right encodings? the same way?

Comment: Again, if your document is declared as being in ISO-8859-1, then all the text in the document must be ISO-8859-1 encoded. To embed characters which are not representable by the chosen encoding, HTML happens to offer you **HTML entities**. The browser will decode those entities to their respective characters and submit them back to the server in the encoding declared on the form.

Comment: Ok i found a solution. The problem was not the wrong encoding or the wrong usage of the encoding function. There is a function, written by someone years ago which converts everything in the post-array to iso-8859-1. harcoded. when i now bypass this forced encoding, my first attempt works like a charm. duh. time wasted

Comment: @Amir Because the answer answers the question as is. That the problem was something entirely different in the end doesn't really matter, does it?

Comment: @deceze Yes, you right, but accepting your answer means it corrected the problem, did it?...and i am in doubt, if `You cannot do anything with character encoding conversion here.` then when we should use `accept-charset="UTF-8`? i down voted you, but personally i like you.

Comment: The question says that the form has `accept-charset="UTF-8"`, and this *does* affect the encoding of form data sent (which is the issue here – not the text on the page itself)

Comment: @Amir, Jukka The data is sent from the form to the server as UTF-8, that works fine. Yet when outputting this UTF-8 encoded data back into the page, **you cannot output it in UTF-8 because the page is declared as ISO-8859.** Since you cannot mix UTF-8 encoded text into ISO-8859 encoded text and the OP doesn't want to change the encoding of the page, HTML entities are the only option! The only other option would be to discard any characters which cannot be encoded in ISO-8859. That was the question and that is the answer. It turned out the OP's problem was somewhere else, but so what?

Comment: @deceze, ok then what is the reason for being `accept-charset` as a form attribute. is it just for sending to the server and not outputting back into the page? do you mean, if we do not declare the page as `ISO-8859` , then it works? if yes, but what about default encoding, as i know is `ISO-8859-1`

Comment: @Amir The `accept-charset` attribute tells the browser how to encode data that is sent to the server. It has nothing to do with the separate problem of how to output this data again back into the page. Maybe read http://kunststube.net/frontback for what's what.

Comment: I am reading the link,thanks. But you mean `accept-charset` as a form attribute only works, if it is the same as page encoding?

Comment: @Amir No. The HTTP `Content-Type` header and/or HTML `<meta>` tags are for telling the browser what the page is encoded in, so the browser can handle it correctly. The form `accept-charset` attribute is for telling the browser how any entered data should be encoded when sent to the server. Encoding of text always needs to be declared, and since there's a two-way communication between server-browser/browser-server these are the two ways to declare the used encodings. Ideally they're the same, but they don't have to be.

Comment: @deceze, i read necessary part of the link like `These two declaration together make it explicit to the browser in which encoding to communicate with the server.`and also your comment.i am satisfied, but it seems the OP ,finally did not remove the `accept-charset="UTF-8"` and also page encoding is ISO-8859. just removed that function and the problem solved. am i true?

Comment: @Amir I don't know what the OP did or what the actual problem was. The answer answers the question, we know nothing else about the details involved and can only speculate about what's happening or not happening.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for the time. please edit something in your post. i need to up vote you.. pleasure